# VB.NET: Convert string to dec in a for-loop

Tags: .net, vb.net, loops, decimal, ascii

So, I want to convert a string to a dec value from this table:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/American_Standard_Code_for_Information_Interchange#ASCII-Table

For example, `"hello"` should be `104101108108111` then (h = 104, e = 101...). Well, I have to use a for-loop for this and I can't seem to get the error.

```
Private Function function1(text As String)
    Dim dec As String
    Dim i As Integer = 0

    For i = 0 To text.Length
        dec = dec & System.Text.ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes(text)(i)
        i += 1
    Next
    Return dec
End Function
```

It works, but it gives me an error if the length of "text" is even (for example, text has got 2, 4, 6 or 8 letters). And when it's uneven (text has got 1, 3, 5, 7 letters), it only converts these uneven letters. So, just as an example. "hello" has got an uneven length (5 letters). So, it does not give me an error. Great! But, it only converts, the "h", the first "l" and the "o" into a dec.

Can anybody explain me why and how to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are incrementing the count `i` in the loop. You don't need to do this in a `For` loop.

Also you are going past the end of the string. You need to end the loop at the `Length - 1`

```
Private Function function1(text As String) As String
    Dim dec As String = ""
    For i As Integer = 0 To text.Length - 1
        dec = dec & System.Text.ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes(text)(i)
    Next
    Return dec
End Function
```

Note: switch option strict on - you will be glad you did in the long run!

Comment: This actually worked! Thank you. And yes, I seem to forgot, that I need to subtract the Length by 1. And also, would you mind explaining me what exactly this "Option Strict On" is? I've read many times about this, but never understood it in docs or something. Why would I need this?

Comment: Have a look here for the definition. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zcd4xwzs.aspx. In your case it would not compile because no return type of the function was specified.

Answer (score 0):

The loop increments itself, don't increment. It is a zero based array so a 14 length text is `0 to 13`.

```
Private Function function1(text As String)
 Dim dec As String = ""
 For i As Integer = 0 To text.Length - 1
    dec = dec & System.Text.ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes(text(i))(0)
    'i += 1 omit this part
 Next
 Return dec
End Function
```

Comment: Oh well! Didn't know that. I've developed in C++ for some weeks now, where I need to increment the int myself (i++). Didn't know that VB.net does that on its own. Anyways, this didn't solved my problem. Now it shoots me an error, regardless of the length of the string. It's an System.IndexOutOfRange error by the way.

Comment: I updated it, you need to get the char by the string's index `text(i)` will do that.

Comment: Now: The &-Operator is not defined for they types "String" and "1-dimensional array" - tried to add a ".toString" after it, but then it only returns System.Byte[] for every single letter.